# AMP tap event to class

Tags: javascript, hide, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I want to hide all div's with specified class. I know how to do it with id, but not find examples for class.

```
<button class="button" 

on="tap:box.hide">hide</button>

<div class="box">text</div>
<div class="box">text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using class DOM object, add amp-bind library and add *AMP.setState*:

```
<script async custom-element="amp-bind" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-bind-0.1.js"></script>

<div hidden [hidden]="hideDivs">Some text</div>
<div hidden [hidden]="hideDivs">Some text</div>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({hideDivs: true})">Hide All</button>
<button on="tap:AMP.setState({hideDivs: false})">Show All</button>
```

This unhide all data in div's on click.